# LOOKUP function in excel

Tags: excel, lookup

Ok so I'm given a range of items and a unit price like so

```
Quantity     Price per Unit
Under 36     $2.85
36-95        $2.63
96-179       $2.27
180+         $2.00
```

So given this data I need to use a LOOKUP function to match the following quantities with their unit prices (it's for an assignment so I have to use the LOOKUP function

```
Quantity     Unit Price
60
24
120
2160
360
120
```

I tried using HLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, and even just a LOOKUP function but I keep receiving #NA! error showing that no value exists for the value.

Comment: Did either of the formulas below work for you? If so please mark the one that worked as correct. It is something only you can do. It will mark the question as answered. If they did not work, some feedback will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to split the lower and upper limits into two columns.  You actually only need the lower limit.

[image]

Then you would just use Vlookup:

[image]

The formula I used:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$5,3)
```

The Vlookup will find where it is greater than but less than the next.

Answer (score 1):

You want your table set up like this:

```
Quantity    Price per Unit
0           $2.85
35          $2.63
95          $2.27
179         $2.00
```

If the table starts in A1 it'd be:

```
=LOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5)
```

where D2 is the target cell you're finding the info for.

At the moment you're trying to match an integer to a string which won't match

Comment: beat you by 5 minutes. :)

Comment: Na, where's the fun in that.